# Command-line tool to show key events, but running in the background

Tags: terminal, x11, xorg, keyboard

Is there a command-line tool that shows "key pressed"-events like `xev`, but is running in the background and doesn't need the input focus?

I want to record terminal input with `asciinema`, using `tmux` to split window and having one window showing the keys I pressed while the other shows the real console input and output.

I am using `Linux nec 5.6.16-1-MANJARO` and running dwm via xinit.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your post to include the OS flavor and version you are using?

Comment: Thank you for editing! Forgive my poor English and description. I am using `Linux nec 5.6.16-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 3 14:26:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and running dwm via xinit.

Comment: Perfect; I was just about to ask you to edit your post to include the information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xinput` may be just the right thing for your problem ([xinput 1 man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput)).

It has a wide range of options, but in your case, if available, I would probably use just the following on one of the splitted windows:

```
xinput test-xi2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I also fount that `sudo showkey` can do the same job.